# Getting Combined Column Attributes with Subqueries

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm working on an exercise where I need to use subqueries but I also need the combined column attributes that you get with joins. For example:
With a join:

```
select A.nameID
from tableA A
join tableB B on (A.nameID = B.nameID)
```

Result: In the final table, I get all of tableA's columns and all of tableB's columns. 
With a query:

```
select A.nameID
from tableA A
where A.nameID in
(
  select B.nameID
  from tableB B
)
```

Result: In the final table, I get only one column, A.nameID

The question is, Is there a way to display the columns that a join produces using subqueries? I'm running SQLS 2008 R2. (Please note that this is not a question about which approach is faster, better or more efficient).

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

See [Subquery Fundamentals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> If a table appears only in a subquery and not in the outer query, then columns from that table cannot be included in the output (the select list of the outer query).